# Cassandra JMX doc pointers

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, jmx

Any good starting URL/pointers for reading up on what could be monitored through JMX on cassandra 2.0?

Think off pull data into an existing ELK stack from JMX on new Cassandra clusters, but never really dealt with JMX before.

Comment: This seems a good [starting point](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Metrics#cache)

Answer (score 0):

My answer for similar question.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107597/cassandra-cluster-monitoring/128385#128385

In your use case you could create script that accesses jmx/jolokia with scripts and writes to log file or directly to ES.

Comment: Thks, I'm running logstash per cass. node anyway, so I ended up using logstash jmx input filter to collect mbeans data into ES, monitoring them via Kibana eta